# How to use binomial properties when proving by induction?

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

Can't seem to find this anywhere, so would really appreciate the help. Looking for an explanation rather than just an answer.

For $n ≥ 1$, verify that
$1^2$ + $3^2$ + $5^2$ + ... + $(2n-1)^2$ = $\binom{2n+1}{3}$

I've tried looking at other examples but I don't understand how the left-hand side could be transformed to a binomial at $n+1$ level.

Answer (score 0):

If you already suspect it sums to $\binom{2n+1}{3}$, induction should be quite straightforward. To find the formula in the first place it's often useful to try small cases.

Answer (score 0):

$1^2 + 3^2 + ... + (2k - 1)^2= ^{2k - 1}C_3$

$^{2k - 1}C_3 + (2k + 1)^2 = \frac{(2k - 1)(2k - 2)(2k -3)}{3!} + (2k + 1)^2$

Simplify the RHS to $\frac{(2k + 1)(2k)(2k - 1)}{3!} = ^{2k + 1}C_3$

In short, formula true for k *and* k + 1

Answer (score 0):

by induction hypothesis,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
1^2+3^2+5^2+\dots+(2k-1)^2&={2n+1 \choose 3}\\ & = \frac{(2k+1)!}{3!(2k-2)!}\\ &=\frac{(2k+1)(2k)(2k-1)}{6}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

now for $n=k+1 $,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 1^2+3^2+5^2+\dots+(2k-1)^2+(2k+1)^2&={2n+1 \choose 3} + (2k+1)^2\\&=\frac{(2k+1)(2k)(2k-1)}{6} + (2k+1)^2 \\&= \frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)(2k+3)}{6} \\ &=\frac{(2k+3)!}{3!(2k)!} \\&={2k+3 \choose 3}\\&= {2(k+1)+1 \choose 3}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence Proved.